# Oracle APEX 5.1 Get the changed value of page item

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am calling a dynamic function on change event of Page Item in my application. But when I save the value of page item in pl/sql it saves the old value of page item. Please help me in this regard how can I get the new value of Page Item in my pl/sql.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add code example to your question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because session state contains the "old" value of an item; run the page in debug mode and have a look at session state info - you should see that. It means that you have to put the "new" value into the session state. How? Submit!